# heightForRowAtIndexPath never being called iOS9

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Alright I'm pretty certain this method has always been executing until now for my `UITableViewController`. I have print statements in my method like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //455(PERFECT MIN HEIGHT) 475 is perfect spacing. 15.5 is the scalar for when descriptionLabel expands lines
    return 475;
    NSLog(@"ISSSS ITTT ONNNN???");

    if (currentDescriptionHeight == 16.0) {
        NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 1111");
        return 475;
    }else if (currentDescriptionHeight == 31.5){
        NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 2222");
        return 490.5;
    }else if (currentDescriptionHeight == 47){
        NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 3333");
        return 506;
    }

    //475 - 1 line description,
}
```

I have copied the method header into my **.h** file, and have correctly set the delegation with:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

in my `viewDidLoad:` method. Why is my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` not being called at all?

Comment: why do you have a return statement at the start of the function?

Comment: Uhm, the method errors because of no return if it's only in the conditionals?

Comment: return statements end the function immediately, therefore the code below it will never execute

Comment: You're right.. okay Ill change that, how do I keep it from returning 475 if I need an open-ended non conditional return statement after the conditionals?

Comment: you can, but it will be the same as just moving the return statement to the end of the function, your choice

Comment: Oh Im an idiot.. If it hits one of the conditionals it'll never reach the bottom. Thanks man. Always gettin tripped up on the easy stuff.

Comment: no problem, maybe i should write an actual answer...

Comment: Maybe.. but I feel this might actually be a duplicate. Who knows I guess it could someone out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the return statement at the top of the function to the bottom or put it in an else as part of the current if statement because the return statement ends the function immediately so the code below it would never execute.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**EDITED**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat height = 475;
NSLog(@"ISSSS ITTT ONNNN???");

if (currentDescriptionHeight == 16.0) {
    NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 1111");
    height = 475;
}else if (currentDescriptionHeight == 31.5){
    NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 2222");
    height = 490.5;
}else if (currentDescriptionHeight == 47){
    NSLog(@"OHHH so it triggered 3333");
    height = 506;
}

return height;
}
```

Comment: This will return `0` if none of the three conditions are true instead of the desired `475`.

Comment: Hope this will return 475 :-)

Comment: Now you just need to change `height` to be `CGFloat` instead of `int`.